# Get a day from week based on Unix timestamp

Tags: java, unix, timestamp

The `Unix timestamp` is `1417029117`, which is 11/26/2014, Wednesday.

```
long timestamp = 1417029117l*1000l;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
System.out.println("current day is "+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
System.out.println("current month is "+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

And I got the results as follows:

```
current day is 4
current month is 10
```

Any explanation? If January is `0` then the month is fine. But why the day is `4`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsure what get(Calendar.DAY\_OF\_WEEK) returns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931152/unsure-what-getcalendar-day-of-week-returns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First day of the week is Sunday. So, Wednesday is 4. See [Calendar#DAY_OF_WEEK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) and [Constant Field Values, Calendar#WEDNESDAY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.WEDNESDAY), it's plain out there in the documentation.

Comment: I am still curious, why does `cal.get(Calendar.WEDNESDAY)` returns `5`?

Comment: Ouch! Why are you passing `Calendar.WEDNESDAY` into `cal.get()`? What should be the meaning of that? "Tell me the Wednesday of the given timestamp?" It's not made for that. `Calendar.WEDNESDAY` is 4. `Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH` also is 4. `cal.get(Calender.WEDNESDAY)` is the same as `cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)`, and it's the 5th week of the month.